# Spring: Injecting services from a different project

Tags: spring, code-injection

In the project our team's working on, we currently have 3 separate Spring projects which utilizes the same services. To avoid redunancy and code copy-pasting, we're planning to create a "common" project wherein all the three projects would be dependent on the common project. In this instance, is it possible to inject these services (perhaps using the @Service annotation) to the Controllers of the Spring projects?

EDIT:

I tried implementing this on my own and what I basically did was I configured the pom.xml to get the Spring Context 3.1.1 dependency (which are also being used by my Spring projects) for my "common" project. With that, I was able to annotate my service with @Service. Afterwards, on my Spring project, I set the component-scan to a level wherein my two projects would meet. On my Spring controller, I @Autowired the service from the "common" project. I ran the Spring project and apparently it worked. Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: You can `import` the Spring context definition files from a JAR by using the `classpath` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

That's absolutely fine, and standard. Spring (unlike CDI) couldn't care less whether your beans come from the current project or from an imported jar.